# why do I keep getting this error: "vNode passed as children has unexpected type" on Stencil?

Tags: javascript, jsx, stenciljs

Why do I keep getting this error when I try to return an HTML element?

```
vNode passed as children has unexpected type.
Make sure it's using the correct h() function.
Empty objects can also be the cause, look for JSX comments that became objects.
```

This is my code:

```
@Prop({ mutable: true }) path: string = '<path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M19.5 13.5v-5a7 7 0 1 0-14 0v5c-.03 2.47-.72 4.887-2 7h18a13.833 13.833 0 0 1-2-7Z"/>'

parseHTML() {
     let template = document.createElement('template');
     template.innerHTML = this.path
     let path = template.content.querySelector("path")
    const SVG = <svg class="inline-svg" width={this.ifxIcon.width} height={this.ifxIcon.height} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"     viewBox="0 0 16 16">{path}</svg>
    return SVG;
}

render() {
return {this.parseHTML()}
}
```

If I copy-paste the path string directly inside the innerHTML of the SVG element, then it works, but if I dynamically insert the path variable, I get this error, and the icon does not get displayed.
Why, and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re actually returning an object instead of just the JSX. Remove the curly braces and the error should disappear:

```
render() {
  return this.parseHTML();
}
```

Comment: The `this.parseHTML()` is actually inside a <div>, and without the braces, I just get a string. If I remove the parent <div>, and only render this `this.parseHTML()`, then I get the same error, and no icon.

Comment: But if I inspect the tool, the svg is rendered, but I don't see any icon.